# What is the difference between SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER, browser.ignoreSynchronization and browser.waitForAngularEnabled() in Protractor?

Tags: automation, protractor

Could anybody explain to me what is the difference between `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER`, `browser.ignoreSynchronization` and `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` in Protractor?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER`

`SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` is the switch to enable/disable the control flow(promise) implemented by Protractor itself. Before ES6, javascript had not supplied native promise API and protractor implemented the promise and promise management (called control flow) by itself.

Now, ES6 supports native promise API and promise management via `await/async` and Protractor intends to change its code to use native promise. So the `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` comes out.

More detail can be found [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow) and [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969)

2) `browser.ignoreSynchronization` and `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()`

The both are switches to tell the Protractor to detect an opening page by `browser.get()` is angular page or not.  `browser.ignoreSynchronization` was introduced at early version, it can also work on high version of Protractor.

`browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` was introduced at higher versions, can't work with low version of protractor.

The idea is `browser.waitForAngularEnabled()` is to be used going forward.
& browser.ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated.

Docs: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled